# Add/remove child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript and jQuery to dynamically add and delete new elements to and from an existing `<div>`.

Adding a new element is working fine, but when I click on 'delete' to remove the element, I get the Main Container object and also the child element object within the button exists and was clicked.

Now the problem comes when I try to delete the element, I am getting the object till the html table control that contains the controls, but do not get the div that is containing the table.

**Note : the div contains the table is the child div/element.**

Javascript

```
var ab = '<table rules="none" width="100%">'+
'<tr>'+
'<td class="optHdBg">'+
'<a><img src="themes/theme_blog/images/icons/delete.png" name="delete"  önclick="javascript:remove_block(this);"/></a>'+
'</td></tr></table>';

function add()
{
  var lstChild = $("#contControls").children().last();
  var containerElement = document.getElementById("contControls");   
  var newElement = document.createElement("div");
  $(newElement).addClass("optionPane");   
  newElement.innerHTML = ab;
  document.getElementById("contControls").appendChild(newElement);
}

function remove_block(obj)
{
  var mainContainer = $(obj).parents("div #contControls");
  var mySelf = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  mainContainer.removeChild(mySelf);
}
```

The problem occurs with `mySelf` control that is not accessing the div control that contains the table, due to that delete operation doesn't work.

Html Code

```
<div id="contControls">
  <div class="optionPane">
    <table rules="none" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="optHdBg">
          <a>
            <img src="themes/theme_blog/images/icons/delete.png" name="delete"  önclick="javascript:remove_block(this);"/>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to get the `<div>` element having class `optionPane`; whenever I try to target the parent of the `<table>` I get the `<div>` with the id `contControls`.

Comment: You can't just split strings in new lines like that they need to be concatenated properly...

Comment: Have you tried emptying `mySelf` first? I seem to recall having a problem deleting an element once which I fixed by emptying the element before removing it.

Comment: @ Gareth yes the mySelf object is undefined. Actually I am not getting the parent control i.e. div having class name "optionPane" of the table control. If I try to get the parent of the **table** control than it gives me the main container which is holding these  new elements

Comment: @ nbrooks  the html is the **var ab** object above. and I'm considering/taking the parent from image tag.

Comment: @manish that small portion does not include `#contControls`, nor does it include the parentNode that you are targeting (you go up about 6 ancestors) -- without seeing an example of a full block we don't know if you are targetting the element correctly. My answer should work regardless, anyway. (p.s. don't leave a space between '@' and 'nbrooks' when replying, otherwise there's no notification).

Comment: @manish I've also updated my answer to include a fully functional demo, take a look and check that it does what you need - http://jsfiddle.net/hcG6b/

Comment: @nbrooks I have update the question and thanks for your guidelines. But my concern is that I'm not able to get the parent of the table control. I'm not getting where I'm lacking means it could be there where I am adding a new element.

Comment: There are several jQuery methods for finding parents/ancestors - my answer below shows how to use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to target the *correct* div. Please have a look at it. I don't know what `embedControls` is, there's no mention/use of it before. Is it a rename of `contControls`? *In any case* trying to count up that many levels of `parentNodes` is not easily maintainable/extensible and, as you have found, tricky to implement. Why not use the tools designed for that?

Comment: @nbrooks I have updated it again. Actually I have spent many hours to review my code again and again so mistakenly it was written wrong. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcG6b/)

If you're going through the trouble of importing jQuery, you may as well use it. It simplifies all of the DOM manipulation that you are trying to accomplish, and your code boils down to simply this (*note that javascript string can't span multiple lines like you are doing without using `+` for concatenation*):

```
var ab = '<table rules="none" width="100%">'
 + '<tr><td class="optHdBg"><a>'
 + '<img src="themes/theme_blog/images/icons/delete.png" name="delete" />'
 + '</a></td></tr></table>';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'img[name="delete"]', function() {
        remove_block(this);
    });        
});

function add() {
    $("<div class='optionPane'></div>").html( ab ).appendTo("#contControls");
}

function remove_block(obj) {
    // remove the entire optionPane <div>
    $(obj).closest('div.optionPane').remove();
}​
```

---

Also, you should note that in the line `$(document).on('click'` you can (*and should*) replace `document` with whichever static parent element you are adding the dynamic elements to (probably `#contControls`, but I can't see your HTML); this provides better performance, because events don't have to bubble as far up the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery code

If you have more than 1 parent node then add after obj

```
$(obj).parent().remove();
```